# Jsoup get class name

Tags: java, jsoup

I parse the elements with

```
 Elements input1 = pageListingParsed.select("form[name=MailForm] textarea");
```

Example output would be:

```
 <textarea name="dec13d35885064571998cc1c81facc28" rows="5" wrap="virtual" class="form-control c-545599b92f2d2b5a09f21c06d490e810"></textarea>
```

How can I get the class names? In that case I would need to assign the `c-545599b92f2d2b5a09f21c06d490e810` to a variable.

Thanks

Comment: alright mate, I got abit confused about what you are asking, what do you want the output be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are sure the element size is 1, then you need to get the first Element and  use method `attr(...)` for it:

```
Element e = input1.get(0);
System.out.println(e.attr("class"));
```

the output will be :

> form-control c-545599b92f2d2b5a09f21c06d490e810

**EDIT:**

to only get the second part, you can simply use `String.split(regex)` method on it.

e.g.

```
String s = "form-control c-545599b92f2d2b5a09f21c06d490e810";
System.out.println(s.contain(" ")? s.split(" ")[1] : s);
```

OUTPUT:

> c-545599b92f2d2b5a09f21c06d490e810

Comment: Thanks that it pretty much what I need. I would however only need the second class name, how can I do that? So in that case c-545599b92f2d2b5a09f21c06d490e810. Thanks!

Comment: @Michael  couldn't u just use `split` on the string?

Comment: Yep, that is what i just did ``.split("\\s+")[1]`` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get all classes of an element with the [JSoup method `classNames`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#classNames--). This is how you would use it:

```
Elements input1 = pageListingParsed.select("form[name=MailForm] textarea");
Set<String> classNames = input1.first().classNames();
```

Note that class names may not come in the same order in the HTML you parse. This is why the method returns a set and not an ordered data structure.